# Condition in while loop using cin

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have following code

```
 //in main
 int x;
 while ( cin>>x ){
        // code goes here
 }
```

Now,i know that this loop executes untill read to `x` fails which occurs when type mismatch occurs
So pressing a `char` lets me to come out of loop as `x` is of type `int` and `char` will not be read from input stream.
But problem is with whitespaces, as they are also not `int` so why loop does not ends when i press enter or whitespace?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of the streams - formatted input skips/breaks on whitespace characters. This is most often what one would want when parsing a textual representation of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [The C++ Programming Language Special Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735), $21.9 Advice [5]:

> Remember that by default >> skips whitespace; §21.3.2.

And in $21.3.2:

> Whitespace is defined as the standard
>   C whitespace (blank, tab, newline, formfeed, and carriage return) by a call to isspace() as defined
>   in  (§20.4.2).

Answer (score 1):

The comment of @jrok provided the answer.

Hence, as long as the input is a white space cin waits for input which may represent the requested type. It stops if an invalid character is in the stream or - after a valid non white space character has been consumed - the character is a white space.

You might read line by line to detect empty input:

```
std::string line
while(getline(cin, line)) {
    // Note: Omitting the case where the line contains spaces, only.
    if(line.empty()) {
       // No input;
       break;
    }
    else {
       // Parse and process the line.
    }
}
```

Note: If skipping white spaces is disabled, the behavior changes.